# Swift 4 view with curved center

Tags: ios, swift, view, uibezierpath, custom-view

i have difficulties to create UI. I tried to create custom view, but i can't see even the background of this view. Here is my sample code, i took it from another post, but i don't know how to change it to my case.

[image]

I do use **SnapKit** for my UI elements.

**My View:**

```
lazy var greenView: CurvedView = {
    let view = CurvedView()
    view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.08778516203, green: 0.7643524408, blue: 0.1997725368, alpha: 1)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        view.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) -> Void in
            make.top.equalTo(self.shipView.snp.bottom).offset(100)
            make.left.right.equalTo(self.scrollContentView)
            make.height.equalTo(200)
        }
    }
    return view
}()
```

**Tried to create custom View:**

```
class CurvedView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        StyleKitName.drawCanvas1(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 400), resizing: .aspectFit)
        backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    }
}
```

**UPDATED** green customView with PaintCode

```
    public class StyleKitName : UIView {

    //// Drawing Methods

    @objc dynamic public class func drawCanvas1(frame targetFrame: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 240, height: 120), resizing: ResizingBehavior = .aspectFit) {
        //// General Declarations
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        //// Resize to Target Frame
        context.saveGState()
        let resizedFrame: CGRect = resizing.apply(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 240, height: 120), target: targetFrame)
        context.translateBy(x: resizedFrame.minX, y: resizedFrame.minY)
        context.scaleBy(x: resizedFrame.width / 240, y: resizedFrame.height / 120)


        //// Color Declarations
        let color = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3411764801, green: 0.6235294342, blue: 0.1686274558, alpha: 1)
        let color2 = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1568627506, blue: 0.07450980693, alpha: 1)

        //// Rectangle Drawing
        let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath()
        rectanglePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 48, y: 103))
        rectanglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 191, y: 103))
        rectanglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 191, y: 9))
        rectanglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 48, y: 9))
        rectanglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 48, y: 103))
        rectanglePath.close()
        color.setFill()
        rectanglePath.fill()


        //// Bezier Drawing
        let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 96, y: 9))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 110, y: 15), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 104.11, y: 9.42), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 107, y: 12))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 123, y: 23), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 114.16, y: 19.16), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 115.63, y: 23))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 136, y: 15), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 129.95, y: 23), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 132, y: 19))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 152, y: 9), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 139.3, y: 11.7), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 145.35, y: 9))
        bezierPath.addCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 96, y: 9), controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 166.7, y: 9), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 96, y: 9))
        bezierPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 148.61, y: 9))
        color2.setFill()
        bezierPath.fill()

        context.restoreGState()

    }




    @objc(StyleKitNameResizingBehavior)
    public enum ResizingBehavior: Int {
        case aspectFit /// The content is proportionally resized to fit into the target rectangle.
        case aspectFill /// The content is proportionally resized to completely fill the target rectangle.
        case stretch /// The content is stretched to match the entire target rectangle.
        case center /// The content is centered in the target rectangle, but it is NOT resized.

        public func apply(rect: CGRect, target: CGRect) -> CGRect {
            if rect == target || target == CGRect.zero {
                return rect
            }

            var scales = CGSize.zero
            scales.width = abs(target.width / rect.width)
            scales.height = abs(target.height / rect.height)

            switch self {
            case .aspectFit:
                scales.width = min(scales.width, scales.height)
                scales.height = scales.width
            case .aspectFill:
                scales.width = max(scales.width, scales.height)
                scales.height = scales.width
            case .stretch:
                break
            case .center:
                scales.width = 1
                scales.height = 1
            }

            var result = rect.standardized
            result.size.width *= scales.width
            result.size.height *= scales.height
            result.origin.x = target.minX + (target.width - result.width) / 2
            result.origin.y = target.minY + (target.height - result.height) / 2
            return result
        }
    }
}
```

https://d.radikal.ru/d30/1902/c5/c07cac5532d0.png

Comment: What is the problem you are having? What is the computer doing that you don't like? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: @robmayoff For now i did just green view, but what i want is view like on screenshot... i tried to use UIBezierPath but still no progress to get result i want.

Comment: Does the screen shot show what you want to draw, or does it show what your code draws now?

Comment: @robmayoff it shows exactly what i want to do.

Comment: Post a screen shot of what your code does now.

Comment: https://c.radikal.ru/c05/1902/4c/ea25180e0828.png
for now i back my view from "CustomView" to "lazy var greenView:UIView", because  CustomView shows nothing but still draw UI inside layers.
Even when i use view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: @robmayoff ok, my bad, draw usually using when u have storyboard UI. I did lazy var greenView:CurvedView with code that i provide in my post. It shows just green square, no visual changes. 
I will update code anyway

Comment: @robmayoff i have idea... i did view with PainCode but don't know how to apply it to my view created with SnapKit

Comment: @GeorgeHeints - are you trying to create a mask? So, the green view is solid green, with the "curved indent" being transparent? Or, the "curved indent" is solid white, and the green is the view showing through? Or, are you just trying to create a green rectangle with a white curved indent?

Comment: @DonMag i update my code, still can't apply my StyleKitName.drawCanvas1 to CurvedView.
It shows me just blank view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the ***basic*** way to use that PaintCode generated code...

```
class StyleView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        StyleKitName.drawCanvas1()
    }
}
class StyleTestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let v = StyleView()
        v.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 240, height: 120)
        v.center = view.center
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.addSubview(v)

    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ok, one moment, if i use SnapKit (no Storyboard), i can't use override func draw(_ rect: CGRect), right?

Comment: Ok, solved.. snapKit update my frame just a step after... =// 
Your answer really helps!